# Is the fact that NSPathControl does not escape percent ('%') characters when bound to a string a bug?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nspathcontrol

Steps:

Environment:
OS X 10.6.4
Xcode 3.2.1

1. Create a new "Application" project.
2. Open the supplied application delegate.
3. Add an `NSString *` property.
4. In `-applicationDidFinishLaunching:` set the string property to `@"/TestString%"`.
5. Open up the NIB.
6. Drag an `NSPathControl` onto the application window.
7. Bind the `NSPathControl`'s value binding to the property created in step 3.
8. Run the application
9. View the console.

You should see the following assertion and the path control will not display:

```
2010-09-15 13:23:39.043 NSPathControlPercentString[83066:a0f] *** Assertion failure in -[NSPathComponentCell _objectValue:forString:errorDescription:], /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1038.32/AppKit.subproj/NSCell.m:1531
2010-09-15 15:33:04.193 NSPathControlPercentString[84028:a0f] Invalid parameter not satisfying: aString != nil
```

If you remove the percent sign from the string in step 4 the assertion will go away and the path control will display properly.

I have tried the following characters and none of them cause the same issue (make sure to escape double quote and backslash):

```
!@#$^&*()_-+=:;'|"\?.,<>~`
```

After doing some debugging I tracked this down to this method supporting percent escapes. e.g. if you use the string `@"/Test%20string"` the result will display "Test string" converting the %20 to a space character.

I haven't found this behavior documented anywhere. Am I missing it?

I encountered this issue because I was using `-[NSBrowser path]` to mirror the browser's path on an `NSPathControl`. If the contents of a selected browser cell contained a % sign the whole `NSPathControl` would fail (QA is great for turning up things like that—many thanks to them).

My best guess is that it attempts to convert the string to an `NSURL` internally which fails returning nil which triggers the exception. This is reinforced by the fact that if you omit the leading / in your string you see the following message:

```
2010-09-15 15:35:55.543 NSPathControlPercentString[84100:a0f] *** -[NSURL initWithScheme:host:path:]: path test!@#$^&*()_-+=:;'|"\?.,<>~` is not absolute.
```

But this is still missing something because `-initWithScheme:host:path:` is documented as adding the required precent escapes, and those methods which could be calling `-initWithScheme:host:path:` and are not documented as adding the escapes (e.g. `-initWithString`) are documented as requiring escapes for characters which cause no issues, namely `:`, `/`, `#`, `;`, and `@`.

I'm planning to file a bug with Apple about it but I wanted to get this documented somewhere and to make sure I'm not missing something first.

---

For anybody finding this question looking for a solution my solution was to manually implement the getter of the property bound to the NSPathControl to return an escaped string using `-stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` and `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.

---

Since nobody had any input I went ahead and filed this with Apple. rdar://8452431.